# android animate() withEndAction() vs setListener() onAnimationEnd()

Tags: android, android-animation, viewpropertyanimator

Often I use ViewPropertyAnimator and set end action using its withEndAction() function like:

```
view.animate().translationY(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}).start();
```

But also you can set end action setting special listener like:

```
view.animate().translationY(0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

So what is the difference between these two approaches and when I should use each of them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no big difference, take a look at the [souce code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.java).

Both are executed on `onAnimationEnd`.

But the runnable gets removed after it was started. 
So The Runnable is just executed once and the Listener might be called multiple times.

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    mView.setHasTransientState(false);
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onAnimationEnd(animation);  // this is your listener
    }
    if (mAnimatorOnEndMap != null) {
        Runnable r = mAnimatorOnEndMap.get(animation); // this is your runnable
        if (r != null) {
            r.run();
        }
            mAnimatorOnEndMap.remove(animation);
    }
    if (mAnimatorCleanupMap != null) {
        Runnable r = mAnimatorCleanupMap.get(animation);  
        if (r != null) {
            r.run();
        }
        mAnimatorCleanupMap.remove(animation);
    }
    mAnimatorMap.remove(animation);
}
```

Comment: No problem. I hope you get some more upvotes. In my opition this was a pretty interesting question. :)